# Let selected users close their own Audits in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I'm using Audit in Phabricator. By default, users cannot close Audits that were created for their own commits. By setting `audit.can-author-close-audit` to `true` it becomes possible for users to close Audits for their own commits.

However, I would like only some people to have this privilege. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anyway to allow for this. Audit support in Phabricator is second class as Differential is the recommended way to do code review. The best way to somewhat enforce this is add a certain user or project to commits that trigger audits through herald so that you or other users will be notified if certain users close their own audits. However this may bring about a somewhat uncomfortable social situation when these users figure out what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. If people don't play nice we might need something like that, but we'll try ordinary peer pressure first :)